# Strange Swift behavior in generic function in NSManagedObjectContext extension

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I'm currently working on an iOS project in Swift and I'm trying to build some sort of extension on top of NSManagedObjectContext using Swift generics and protocols. I have already implemented some methods like the one below:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

   func objectWhere<T: NSManagedObject>(entityClass: T.Type, predicate: NSPredicate) -> T? {
       let entityName = NSStringFromClass(entityClass)
       let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)

       //...fetch object code here

       return result?.first
   }
}
```

This method works fine, but the trickyness comes when I want to implement an upsert. Basically what I'm doing is creating a protocol like so:

```
protocol Updatable {
     static func primaryKeyJSON() -> String

     static func primaryKey() -> String

     func populate(JSON: [NSObject: AnyObject], context: NSManagedObjectContext)

     func update(JSON: [NSObject: AnyObject], context: NSManagedObjectContext)
}
```

The next thing I do is extend one of my NSManagedObject subclasses with this protocol. In my current project for example I have a class named Person which implements this protocol. This protocol should allow me to create an upsert method in the same NSManagedObjectContext extension like this:

```
func upsert<T where T: NSManagedObject, T: Updatable>(entityClass: T.Type, JSON: [NSObject: AnyObject]) -> T? {
    return nil
}
```

The problem is however that whenever I call this method Xcode gives an error saying: "Expected member name or constructor call after type name".

```
c.upsert(Person, JSON: ["test": "sometest"])
```

The strangest thing is however that the first method from this question works perfectly fine. Also, when I remove the JSON: parameter form the upsert function it doesn't give that error and compiles and runs completely fine.

Can someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: I cannot explain why, but if you write upsert(Person.self ... i will compile. Might be worth a radar.

Comment: Hmm that does indeed compile, strange that all the other methods work without the .self though. I will check if I can file a radar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think a type of a class/structure or protocol is returning implicit it's type. However it happens when you only have one parameter in your function like `T.Type`.

Here is what [Apples Swift Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html) says:

> You can use the postfix **self** expression to access a type as a value. For example, **SomeClass.self** returns SomeClass itself, not an instance of SomeClass. And **SomeProtocol.self** returns SomeProtocol itself, not an instance of a type that conforms to SomeProtocol at runtime.

This may change in the future, my fingers are also crossed. But for now you will have to type the `self` postfix when you have more then one parameter in your function.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {}

func someFunc1<T: SomeProtocol>(_: T.Type) -> String { "\(T.self)" }
func someFunc2<T: SomeProtocol>(_: T.Type, someInt: Int) -> String { "\(T.self) + \(someInt)"}

extension Int : SomeProtocol {}

someFunc1(Int) // returns "Swift.Int" <--- this is a bug
someFunc1(Int.self) // returns "Swift.Int"

someFunc2(Int, someInt: 42) // Expected memeber name or constructer call after type name
someFunc2(Int.self, someInt: 42) // returns "Swift.Int + 42"
```

Btw. I think you can modify your code a little like this:

```
func objectWhere<T: NSManagedObject>(_: T.Type, predicate: NSPredicate) -> T? {
    let entityName = "\(T.self)"
    /* ... */
}
```

**UPDATE**: The issue is just a bug, read [here](https://twitter.com/jckarter/status/619898218151743488):